# Process Priorities for Sharepoint FAST Search Services

Tags: sharepoint, process-priority

I have 4 servers dedicated to sharepoint. One of them has sharepoint, one of them has sql server and other two of them are FAST Search nodes. Sharepoint server and sql server works without a problem. But fast nodes crash/freeze after a day of a full or incremental crawl and they force me to reset the machines. In brief, I want to set "low" priority for the FAST Search Services in the nodes. But I don't know how to do it. 
FAST nodes have 4GB RAM, 3 Core CPU on each, I think it is enough for FAST Search.